# scrapy crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm learning scrapy and wanted to scrapy a few items from this page:
https://www.gumtree.com/search?sort=date&search_category=flats-houses&q=box&search_location=Vale+of+Glamorgan

To avoid robots.txt policies etc I've saved the page on my hd and tested my xpaths using scrapy shell. They seem to work as expected. But when I run my spider with the `scrapy crawl basic` command (as it's recommended in the book I'm reading) I got the following output:

```
    2017-09-27 12:05:02 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: properties)
2017-09-27 12:05:02 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'USER_AGENT': 'Mozila/5.0', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['properties.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'properties', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'properties.spiders'}
2017-09-27 12:05:03 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-09-27 12:05:03 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-09-27 12:05:03 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-09-27 12:05:03 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-09-27 12:05:03 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-09-27 12:05:03 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-09-27 12:05:03 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6026
2017-09-27 12:05:03 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET file:///home/albert/Documents/programming/python/scrapy/properties/properties/tests/test_page.html> (referer: None)
2017-09-27 12:05:04 [basic] DEBUG: title: 
2017-09-27 12:05:04 [basic] DEBUG: price: 
2017-09-27 12:05:04 [basic] DEBUG: description: 
2017-09-27 12:05:04 [basic] DEBUG: address: 
2017-09-27 12:05:04 [basic] DEBUG: image_urls: 
2017-09-27 12:05:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-09-27 12:05:04 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 262,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 270547,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 27, 9, 5, 4, 91741),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 50790400,
 'memusage/startup': 50790400,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 27, 9, 5, 3, 718976)}
2017-09-27 12:05:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
igor@foobard:properties$ scrapy crawl basic
2017-09-27 12:10:13 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: properties)
2017-09-27 12:10:13 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'SPIDER_MODULES': ['properties.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'properties', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'properties.spiders', 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozila/5.0'}
2017-09-27 12:10:13 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole']
2017-09-27 12:10:13 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-09-27 12:10:13 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-09-27 12:10:13 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-09-27 12:10:13 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-09-27 12:10:13 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-09-27 12:10:13 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6026
2017-09-27 12:10:13 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET file:///home/albert/Documents/programming/python/scrapy/properties/properties/tests/test_page.html> (referer: None)
2017-09-27 12:10:13 [basic] DEBUG: title: 
2017-09-27 12:10:13 [basic] DEBUG: price: 
2017-09-27 12:10:13 [basic] DEBUG: description: 
2017-09-27 12:10:13 [basic] DEBUG: address: 
2017-09-27 12:10:13 [basic] DEBUG: image_urls: 
2017-09-27 12:10:13 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-09-27 12:10:13 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 262,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 270547,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 27, 9, 10, 13, 927817),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 51032064,
 'memusage/startup': 51032064,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 27, 9, 10, 13, 722731)}
2017-09-27 12:10:13 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Here's my **items.py**:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class PropertiesItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    price = Field()
    description = Field()
    address = Field()
    image_urls = Field()

    images = Field()
    location = Field()

    url = Field()
    project = Field()
    spider = Field()
    server = Field()
    date = Field()
```

And here's the spider **basic.py**:

```
import scrapy


class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'basic'
    start_urls = ['file:///home/albert/Documents/programming/python/scrapy/properties/properties/site/test_page.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log('title: '.format(response.xpath(
            "//h2[@class='listing-title' and not(span)]/text()").extract()))
        self.log('price: '.format(response.xpath(
            "//meta[@itemprop='price']/@content").extract()))
        self.log("description: ".format(response.xpath(
            "//p[@itemprop='description' and not(span)]/text()").extract()))
        self.log('address: '.format(response.xpath(
            "//span[@class='truncate-line']/text()[2]").re('\|(\s+\w+.+)')))
        self.log('image_urls: '.format(response.xpath(
            "//noscript/img/@src").extract()))
```

The xpaths are a little clumsy but they work. But nevertheless the items are not collected. I'd like to know why.

Comment: Add `print(response.body)` and `print(type(response))` in the parse function see and if you get HTMLResponse and the correct body with all expected HTML?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Let me check it. But I've tried running this saved page in scrapy shell and implementing the xpaths and they worked fine which, I concluded, is the sign that the html body is correct.

Comment: @TarunLalwani `print(type(response))` yields `<class 'scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse'>` and `print(response.body)` prints the body of the html document. At first sight, everything seems fine.

Comment: I think I found the issue, posted the answer with issues in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the you have not inserted the output from the format function anywhere in the string. So you need to change `title` to `title {}`, so the format inserts the values. Also use `extract_first()` instead of `extract()`. So you get an a string output instead of array

```
class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'basic'
    start_urls = ['file:///home/albert/Documents/programming/python/scrapy/properties/properties/site/test_page.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log('title: {}'.format(response.xpath(
            "//h2[@class='listing-title' and not(span)]/text()").extract_first()))
        self.log('price: {}'.format(response.xpath(
            "//meta[@itemprop='price']/@content").extract_first()))
        self.log("description: {}".format(response.xpath(
            "//p[@itemprop='description' and not(span)]/text()").extract_first()))
        self.log('address: {}'.format(response.xpath(
            "//span[@class='truncate-line']/text()[2]").re('\|(\s+\w+.+)')))
        self.log('image_urls: {}'.format(response.xpath(
            "//noscript/img/@src").extract_first()))
```

Comment: ooooh my....I didn't notice it....I can't believe I missed it...I feel so stupid...
Thank you! Yeah now it works the way it should!

Answer (score 1):

I don't try Scrapy in local file, but if you want to scrapy something, you have to init `Items` first and have to assignment `Item` as `dict` in python, finally `yield item` to `pipeline`

```
import scrapy
from properties.items import PropertiesItem

class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'basic'
    start_urls = ['file:///home/albert/Documents/programming/python/scrapy/properties/properties/site/test_page.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = PropertiesItem()     # init Item
        # assignment 
        item['title'] = response.xpath("//h2[@class='listing-title' and not(span)]/text()").extract()
        item['price'] = response.xpath("//h2[@class='listing-title' and not(span)]/text()").extract()
        item['description'] = response.xpath("//h2[@class='listing-title' and not(span)]/text()").extract()
        item['address'] = response.xpath("//h2[@class='listing-title' and not(span)]/text()").extract()
        item['image_urls'] = response.xpath("//h2[@class='listing-title' and not(span)]/text()").extract()
        # yield item
        yield item
```

Comment: hmm yeah this code makes much more sense than what's written in the tutorial I'm following. Actually, they scrape some other site but I was just repeating their code with all the modyfications needed to scrape the site I wanted to. I don't understand how come their example works when written this way...
Thank you for clarifying it! And by the way, it should be `from properties.items import PropertiesItem`.

Comment: Yeah it should be `from properties.items import PropertiesItem`, I edit it